# Predict customer’s payments. [Data science interview case]

Tags: bigdata, prediction, data-science

I had an interview for a junior data science position for one European bank and I got this case:

> We want to develop model that will be able to predict customers future
>   expenses. Assume we have data about all transactions that were made
>   by clients (Time, amount, recipient etc) for several years.

I suppose firstly we should try to predict monthly payments, such as insurance, water or the internet, but I'm completely clueless as to which algorithm to use. 
Could you kindly help me where to start or what to read?

Comment: This seems related to homework questions (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), which are fine on their own. But they do require that you show a good faith attempt to answer the question yourself, and would benefit from more specific details. Was this a "verbal" case in which you had to explain your thoughts? Was this a "take-home" test where the data was provided? Are you debating among algorithms for specific reasons, or are you unsure of how to begin with choosing a specific target and features?

Comment: Hi @SavageHenry, thank you for your answer! It was just a verbal case during the interview! I asked about algorithms because I have no idea how to answer this question. I said something like that we need to find patterns and trends in data, check which payments are done each month, but it was not the best answer I suppose :) I just don't understand how to deal with such cases

Answer (score 0):

The term *future expenses* is ambiguous, in particular it could mean [NPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_present_value), which is sum of all future *weight adjusted* cashflows. That would be a bit more complicated, because the discount factor is another random variable. I suppose we should talk about payment estimate over some period, e.g. a month.

I think you were on the right track initially: regular payments (mortgage, internet, utilities, etc) are easier to predict, some of them may even have very strict schedule. In addition, there are random payments that certainly have a different distribution.

I would approach it this way (not 100% sure it's the best way, but at least seems reasonable): fit regular and irregular payments into two different distributions, i.e. different models.

- Irregular payments can be modeled via [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which parameters can be inferred from the history. This distribution has high variance, but assuming the distribution won't change drastically in the future, in the long run the computed expectation will be close to the true mean ([LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)).
- Regular payments over a period can be viewed as a time series. My first idea would be to predict it with machine learning (regression problem, e.g. `x(n) -> x(n+1)` or `[x(n-1), x(n)] -> x(n+1)`), because in general there seems to be a pattern. But in reality a choice of algorithm greatly depends on the data. It's possible to have [seasonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality) present in the time series, which of course would affect the choice.

Having the model for both sources of payments, we can estimate total expenses. By the way, if the employer had any comments about this question, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting future expenses
Use Linear regression algorithm for this

Answer (score 0):

The target here is to determine if a customer will complete a payment or not. This is a critical metric for companies. For this classification machine learning problem, features such as affluence, economic conditions, and seasonality will be important to determine the likelihood that an individual customer will complete payment assuming individual customer level data is available. An algorithm such as logistic regression or a tree-based approach would then predict provide a probabilistic outcome for each customer. This can then be aggregated across customer and visualized in BI tools such as Power BI or Tableau.

Sources: Kaggle: [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com), AceAI Interviews: [AceAI](https://aceainow.com)